# Create user story using Microsoft teams

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams, azure-boards

Is there a way to automatically create a User Story in Azure Boards, based on messages in a Microsoft Teams channel?
So, whenever any message is posted in Teams, a User Story should be created.

Comment: Why don't you just create a user story in Azure Boards _instead of_ posting a message in a Teams channel?

Comment: My intention is to have a public channel where users can post questions and corresponding to them, a user story should be created.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

first you'll need a bot that can be created using Microsoft Bot Framework.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/channel-connect-teams?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#:~:text=To%20add%20the%20Microsoft%20Teams,Get%20bot%20embed%20code%20dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/channel-connect-teams?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#:%7E:text=To%20add%20the%20Microsoft%20Teams,Get%20bot%20embed%20code%20dialog).

Then, use the Azure Devops Rest API to create the user story:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

PS: note the ${type} in the url, it's where you set 'User Story'

Comment: Hello @Jaimin Joshi, Is the above solution worked for you? Could you please confirm once.